# JBoss deploy failed: "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, war

Suddenly my project gets an error when deploying. The error I get is `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` and I've read one possibility is to change the `metaspace max size` with this line of code:

```
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=3200m
```

In which file I need to put this option? Also there is a better way whithout modifying default settings?

Comment: Since the Metaspace is unbounded by default, you actually should *remove* that option. Obviously, there must be a JBoss configuration already containing such an option with a too small value. I suppose, JBoss has some documentation about its configuration options…

Comment: @Holger I changed it a few times but I'm not sure if I'm puttin the right sizes or it's the ritght file. I'll have to search a bit more about it...

Comment: As said, don’t guess about “the right sizes”, just *remove it*. Remove every occurrence of it.

Answer (score 0):

`-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=3200m` is `java` argument. You have to add it to all other arguments like `-cp`.

Which file is depends on how you start your application.

Comment: But having no main function NetBeans doesn't allow me to add parameters when executing a file. How do I set it?